What is the formal definition of the commutative property occurring in an equation?
This question was inspired by something I saw in an elementary algebra textbook. In one of the exercises of that book, the author asked what property an equation exemplified. For example, the equation $$(3+x)+2=3+(x+2) \tag1$$ exemplifies the associative property of addition.
Most of the exercises were straightforward, but the last one was a bit trickier. It was this equation:
$$4\cdot(3+5)=4\cdot(5+3) \tag2$$ In the solutions to the exercises, the author said it was the commutative property of addition. But that is not technically true, because the outermost operation is multiplication, not addition.
I guess what the book is looking for is a "generalized" definition of the commutative property of addition occurring in an equation.
To give an example, under the generalized definition, the equation $$(3+2)+6=(2+3)+6 \tag3$$ is an instance of the commutative property of addition. It is this generalized definition that I want a formalization of.

More precisely, given an equation $s=t$, where $s$ and $t$ are terms, what is the definition of that equation being a generalized example of the commutative property?

Of course, one could ask this question about other equational properties, like the associative property, or the distributive property.

"[T]he author said [equation (2) exhibited] the commutative property of addition. But that is not technically true, because the outermost operation is multiplication, not addition." ... The commutative property of addition states that $a+b=b+a$, so that you can swap addends wherever you encounter them (ie, not just when addition is the "outermost operation"). In $(2)$, the $3$ and $5$ are legitimately swapped by virtue of this property. Likewise for $(3)$: You're simply applying the property to the addends $2$ and $3$, which change places from $3+2$ to $2+3$.

Given $x = y$ where $x$ and $y$ live in the domain of a function $f$, we can always conclude $f(x) = f(y)$. Call this operation on equalities congruence. Then what you are looking for are congruences of the commutativity of addition, i.e. equations of the form $f(x + y) = f(y + x)$. In your example, $f(x) = x + 6$. You could possibly generalise this to $n$-ary functions, i.e. $f(x + y, a + b, \dots) = f(y + x, b + a, \dots)$.
